# SpriteKit moving Nodes faster with time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, skaction

I want to spawn the Objects faster with time, for e.g. I got a Object added every 1.5 seconds. This Object is moving to X = -100 with Duration = 5. After 30 seconds it should move faster.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

..... 

SKAction * Spawn = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(Enemy) onTarget:self];
SKAction * Delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.5];
SKAction * SpawnThenDelay = [SKAction sequence:@[Spawn, Delay]];
SKAction * SpawnThenDelayForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:SpawnThenDelay];
[self runAction:SpawnThenDelayForever];

.....
}

- (void)Enemy {

Enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Enemy.png"];
Enemy.size = CGSizeMake(85, 85);
Enemy.zPosition = 2;
Enemy.name = @"Enemy";

Enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
Enemy.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
Enemy.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
Enemy.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
Enemy.physicsBody.restitution = 0;

Enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = EnemyCategory;
Enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = StoneCategory;
Enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = StoneCategory;

Enemy.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 1.25, self.frame.size.height / 2.2);


SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveToX:-100 duration:5];
SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];

[Enemy runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove,actionMoveDone]]]];

[self addChild:Enemy];
}
```

Comment: Add your sprites in the `update:` method. Look at the time stamp of the correct frame to control spawn rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every SKAction has a property speed and by defult every action runs with a speed of 1 so you can increase speed property acc to your game situation

Comment: Yes, I could use the SKAction SpeedTo, but I want to speed up my Enemy after 30 seconds in the game.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your enemy speed as global variable and add a NSTimer with a 30 seconds interval and every 30 seconds, the timer executes a function that adds a certain value to the speed of the enemy. But make sure there's a speed limit otherwise it will be too fast.

MyScene.h:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MyScene : SKScene {
    NSTimer *timer;
    int SpeedVar;
    int MaxSpeed;
    int IncreaseSpeedValue;
}

@end
```

MyScene.m:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(increaseSpeed) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        SpeedVar = -100;  //Normal speed of your enemy
        MaxSpeed = -300;  //Maximum speed of your enemy 
        IncreaseSpeedValue = 15; //Increase speed by this value every 30sec
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)increaseSpeed {

    if (SpeedVar > MaxSpeed)
        SpeedVar -= IncreaseSpeedValue;
    else {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}
```